# On Checkbox Changed Copy Values to textbox jquery

Tags: php, jquery

On Checkbox Changed event I am copying hidden values to my textbox,
now when I try to add value using jquery its gives me [Object object].
    HTML Code

```
My hidden variables values
    <div class="reserve-form">
    <span>Name: </span><span><?php echo $user_data[0]->first_name.' '.$user_data[0]->last_name; ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="name_account" value="<?php echo $user_data[0]->first_name.' '.$user_data[0]->last_name; ?>" />
     </span>
     <span>Email Address: </span><span><?php echo $user_data[0]->email_id; ?>
     <input type="hidden" id="email_account" value="<?php echo $user_data[0]->email_id; ?>" />
     </span>
     <span>Phone Number: </span><span><?php echo $user_data[0]->phone_no; ?>
     <input type="hidden" id="phoneno_account" value="<?php echo $user_data[0]->phone_no; ?>">
     </span>

     <div class="passenger-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="duplicate_info" id="duplicate_info" class="css-checkbox" />
     <label for="duplicate_info" class="css-label">Is passenger info same as account holder</label>
     </div>
     </div>

    **Where I need to append it** 
    <div id="passanger_info">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name[]" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_address[]" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email Address">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number[]" name="phone_number[]" placeholder="Phone Number">
     <button type="button" class="removebtn"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
   </div>

$("#duplicate_info").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) 
    {
       isChecked();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Unchecked")
    }
});


 function isChecked()
    {
        //hidden variables values
        var name_account = $('#name_account').val();
        var email_account = $('#email_account').val();
        var phoneno_account = $('#phoneno_account').val();
        alert(name_account);
        var name = $('#name').val(name_account);
        alert(name);
        var email_address = $('#email_address').val(email_account);
        var phone_number = $('#phone_number').val(phoneno_account);

    }
```

It's like when I copy `name_account`  to `name` and try to alert the `name` it gives me `Object Object` instead of values. What I am missing?

Comment: ty to set the value `$('#name').val(name_account);` and then take it `var name = $('#name').val()`, on 2 seperated lines

Comment: didn't got it, can you pls share me the code in answer section?

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the value, before you take from it.

setting value = `$('#name').val(name_account)`
taking the value = `var name = $('#name').val();`

The problem in your code is `[]` in your id

```js
$("#duplicate_info").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    isChecked();
  } else {
    alert("Unchecked")
  }
});


function isChecked() {
  //hidden variables values
  var name_account = $('#name_account').val();
  console.log("input val of #name_account is : " + name_account);
  $('#name').val(name_account)
  var name = $('#name').val();
  console.log("input val of #name is : " + name);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reserve-form">
  <span>Name: </span><span>Carsten
    <input type="hidden" id="name_account" value="Carsten" />
     </span>
  <span>Email Address: </span><span><?php echo $user_data[0]->email_id; ?>
     <input type="hidden" id="email_account" value="<?php echo $user_data[0]->email_id; ?>" />
     </span>
  <span>Phone Number: </span><span><?php echo $user_data[0]->phone_no; ?>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="phoneno_account" value="<?php echo $user_data[0]->phone_no; ?>">
                                </span>
  <div class="passenger-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="duplicate_info" id="duplicate_info" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="duplicate_info" class="css-label">Is passenger info same as account holder</label>
  </div>
</div>

**Where I need to append it**
<div id="passanger_info">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_address[]" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email Address">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number[]" name="phone_number[]" placeholder="Phone Number">
  <button type="button" class="removebtn"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Undefined only let me add my html code and upadte it

Comment: Updated the answer, remove []

Comment: But I need [] because I have Add More Button Which Will add append same div below so I cant remove it as it will have then same id

Comment: They are the problem. You can't use special characters like these in your id field.

Comment: OK Never Mind I will Change it, Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @JayminsFakeAccount No problem.

Comment: Upvoted :) If You feel like you can also upvote my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Check below example:

Fill up the details and click on checkbox.

```js
$("#duplicate_info").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) 
    {
       isChecked();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Unchecked")
    }
});


function isChecked()
{
    //hidden variables values
    var name_account = $('#name_account').val();
    var email_account = $('#email_account').val();
    var phoneno_account = $('#phoneno_account').val();
    alert(name_account);
    $('#name').val(name_account);
    var name = $('#name').val();
    alert(name);
    var email_address = $('#email_address').val(email_account);
    var phone_number = $('#phone_number').val(phoneno_account);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
My hidden variables values
        <div class="reserve-form">
        <span>Name: </span><span>
        <input type="hidden" id="name" value="" />
         </span>
         <span>Email Address: </span><span>
         <input type="hidden" id="email_account" value="" />
         </span>
                                    <span>Phone Number: </span><span>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="phoneno_account" value="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="passenger-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="duplicate_info" id="duplicate_info" class="css-checkbox" />
                                        <label for="duplicate_info" class="css-label">Is passenger info same as account holder</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

        **Where I need to append it** 
        <div id="passanger_info">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_account" name="name_account[]" placeholder="Name">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_address" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email Address">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" name="phone_number[]" placeholder="Phone Number">
         <button type="button" class="removebtn"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
       </div>
```

Comment: It is giving me undefined error I have tried your code

Comment: Run code snippet and check its working fine. @JayminsFakeAccount If you are getting error in your code then need to check where its giving you undefined.

Comment: Ok, try to add it in code snippet so we can easily change it and resolve it. @JayminsFakeAccount

Comment: Remove [] from id and check. @JayminsFakeAccount

Comment: No issues I have changed the code and removed [] from the code. TY for the help :)